# Question about closed sets and connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have this theorem.

let $A$ and $B$ two closed sets of a topological space $E$, such that $A\cap B$ and $A\cup B$ are connected, then $A$ and $B$ are connected.

I want to prove it directly without contradiction.

To prove that $A$ is connected I let $f:A\to (\{0,1\},P(\{0,1\})) $ continuous and I must prove that $f$ is constant.

As $A\cap B$ is connected we deduce that $f: A\cap B\subset A\to \{0,1\}$ is constant

But I don't know how to continue? how to use that $A$ is closed?

Thank you.

Comment: You use closedness in order to apply the "pasting lemma" as Thomas does in his answer (defining a function on finitely many closed pieces). This does not work for general subsets.

Comment: @henno I don't understand what is pasting lemma?

Comment: That's the lemma that implies that Thomas' function is continuous on $A \cup B$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma), e.g. It's in many texts.

Comment: @henno $g^{-1}(\{b\})=\emptyset$?

Comment: What is $b$? I don't see your point.

Comment: sorryi mena 1 instead of b

Comment: $g^{-1}(\{1\})=\emptyset$ @henno

Comment: Then $g$ is constantly $0$ and we're done.

Comment: yes so i'm right the inverse of 1 is the emptyset

Comment: @HennoBrandsma please what is $g^{-1}(\{0,1\})$ is it $A\cup B$ or $B$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:A\to \{0,1\}$ be a continuous function. Note that $f$ restricted to $A\cap B$ is a constant, say $0$. Define $$g:A\cup B\to \{0,1\},\,g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x),&x\in A\\0,&x\in B\end{cases}.$$ Note that $g$ is continuous and hence a constant function. Can you complete now?